# Show default image in case ADF image source is not found

Tags: image, oracle-adf

I am generating the source for `af:image` on runtime. Sometimes, when a source path is generated at runtime, there is no image at that source path. So in that case `shortDesc` field of that image is displayed instead. Is there a way to catch the exception (if thrown any) in that case and a default image can be shown instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem before and one solution I could come up with is providing a CSS background fallback, that way you can have default picture in case there is no image at the destination

Comment: Is there no way to check the validity of a URI.

Comment: You can do that by making Internet call using servlet or something and if it has 404 you can load another source, I just wanted to give you a quick solution without the need to write any external java code

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using javascript. The img element has an onerror event which you can listen to.

Example:

```
<img src="idontexist.jpg" onerror="handleMissingImg" />
```

The only problem is that ADF does not expose that attribute for the image tag.

See [How to silently hide "Image not found" icon when src source image is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found)