# how to hide "image not found" icon on IE and chrome using CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have some images on my page.

By default if a given image is not available, then the broken image indicator is shown on Chrome and IE.

I want *nothing* to be shown but the alternative text in this case. Is there any way to handle it using CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found

Answer (score 13):

using javascript

```
<img src="broken.png" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

edit: added small snipet that will handle all images.

```
$("img").error(function(){$(this).hide();});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Va2Wd/

Comment: This is ok for an example, but if the OP is doing this for a lot of images, the JS should _not_ be inline

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `alt=" "` as an empty string, If the image isn't found, there will just be an empty space.

Comment: Chrome doesn't hide icons of broken images though, where OP wants to hide those icons

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On IE also broken image appears and i want it to do it using CSS not JS, if any option is available please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onerror event in JavaScript to act when an image fails to load:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.onerror = function () { 
    this.style.display = "none";
}
```

or use

```
var images=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(i=0;img[i]!=null;i++)
{
img[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JavaScript or CSS, you can use the object tag. It's cleaner and easier code. Add alternative text between the tags like this:

```
<object data="img/failedToLoad.png" type="image/png">Alternative Text</object>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp