# Rotate Image Alt Text Without Rotating Image

Tags: html, css

I have `alt` attributes for my images.  When an image is unavailable, I'd like the text to be displayed diagonally at a 45* angle of where the image should be.  I've tried using the transform / rotate property in CSS, but this tilts displayed images also.

Is there a way to tilt only the alt text?

Comment: how are you checking an image is unavailable?

Comment: Ok, I tried to make a clever answer, but don't have access to a machine with a decent browser. I think this should be possible using the [onerror event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found). If you override that, you could hide the image and insert a span after with the alt text and rotate that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in CSS, because the `alt` text does not exist as a CSS concept. CSS is applied to elements, and the `alt` text does not constitute an element, even a pseudo-element. There is no way in CSS to make the application of a rule depend on the status of an `img` element. And in practice, the rendering of `alt` texts, and the rendering of an `img` element as a whole when the image is not available, greatly varies by browser.

Even if you unconditionally rotate the element (meaning that the image is rotated, too, when the image is displayed), the `alt` text will not behave as desired in all browsers. (Firefox would rotate the image, but not the `alt` text.)

A workaround, using scripting, would be to replace `img` elements by their `alt` texts, wrapped in elements that you can rotate. The bad news is that you would need to add an `onerror` attribute in each `img` element in markup. You cannot do this with scripting, since it would be too late to add the attribute when the element has already been parsed, since on parsing, the browser also sends a request for the image. And you cannot use the `complete` property of an `img` element, since it gets set to `true` when a request for the image fails – there is no direct way in JavaScript to test whether an `img` element is rendered as an image or not.

So you would use, say, `onerror=altr()` in all of your `img` elements, with the function definition

```
function altr(el) {
console.log(el.innerHTML);
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'notLoaded';
  span.innerHTML = el.alt || 'Missing alt';
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(span, el);
}
```

and with the CSS code

```
span.notLoaded {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid thin;
    color:red;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);        
}
```

If you wish to show the `alt` text in a box that has some specific dimensions, like those specified in the `img` element, you would need to add code that puts those dimensions into the `style` property of the `span` element created here.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/AEFBD/)

Comment: Is there a way to rotate the image, but not rotate alt, when image is not available?