# asp.net load server side url but don't open page or window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to load URL from server side and the url is an API that sends SMS.

My problem is I need to load the url but that should not open a page or any window when that is triggered.

```
string url = "http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=xxxx&pass=xxxx&sender=xxx&phone=xxxxxxxxxxx&text=this%20is%20test%20sms&priority=ndnd&stype=normal";
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

Comment: Not sure how it is set up. But read about Ajax.  It might help. Here are some [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could send an ajax `GET` request from the client, although I don't understand why you are not calling this URL from the server side instead.

This would be server side:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    string url = "http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=xxxx&pass=xxxx&sender=xxx&phone=xxxxxxxxxxx&text=this%20is%20test%20sms&priority=ndnd&stype=normal";
    client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

If you choose do it on client side, you can use this code:

```
string url = "http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=xxxx&pass=xxxx&sender=xxx&phone=xxxxxxxxxxx&text=this%20is%20test%20sms&priority=ndnd&stype=normal";
string s = "var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();";
s += "xmlHttp.open('GET'," + url + ", false);";
s += "xmlHttp.send(null);";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

Comment: i would prefer server side but where should i add url and what do u mean address is it a url

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I modified my answer.

Comment: No issue but now `WebClient` is underlined by red line and says the type of web `WebClient` could not be found

Comment: Add `using System.Net;` to the bottom of the page (there should be other `using ...` lines there).

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `window.open`, You can use `iframe` with `display:none` and then change url of this `iframe`.

Please find the code below.

**Using RegisterStartupScript**

ASPX

```
<div ID="myCustomDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateDiv(content) {
        document.getElementById("myCustomDiv").innerHTML = content;
    }
</script>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "updateDiv(\"<iframe style='display:none' src='http://stackoverflow.com'></iframe>\");";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", url, true);
    }
```

**Another approach during pageload**

ASPX

```
<div runat="server" ID="myCustomDiv"></div>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string iframeString = "<iframe style=\"display:none\" src=\"http://stackoverflow.com\"></iframe>";

            myCustomDiv.InnerHtml=iframeString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share the same with an example if you dont mind

Comment: i am on it... in some time i'll update my response with example

Comment: added code. i verified approach using fiddler its working

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to open in the current window,
 then replace the `'popup_window'` with `'_self'`

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole slew of ways to accomplish this  task:

1. Use AJAX to send a GET or POST request to this URL.  This is easily done via the regular [browser api](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) or via [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
2. You can load an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) which is set to have minimal width/height, or just [no display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).
3. You could just add an `img` tag to the page, with the `src` attribute set to the url of your API.  If you use this option, then it would be best to find a way to hide the [image not found icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found).

The browser is designed to send requests, so it has many ways to do so, all of which will have their own properties and trade-offs.  I recommend looking into the many ways to accomplish this and choose which best fits your particular use case.  Good luck!