# Hide parent element if img src = null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide the td containing the image if the image src inside of the td is null.

I tried the following, but it would hide more than just the td i was trying to target:

```js
$('td').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').attr('src') == "null"){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="centered">
          <label class="wrapable">
          <img src="null">
          <input name="test" value="1" type="radio">
          </label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="centered">
          <label class="wrapable">
          <img src="null">
          <input name="test" value="1" type="radio">
          </label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="centered">
          <label class="wrapable">
          <img src="null">
          <input name="test" value="1" type="radio">
          </label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="centered">
          <label class="wrapable">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
          <input name="test" value="1" type="radio">
          </label>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, still learning :)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work ? It looks like it does.

Comment: "it would hide more than just the td i was trying to target:" . What else it does it hide, then? It looks to me like it should work.

Comment: Note that you can simplify it in `$('img[src="null"]').closest("td").hide();`

Comment: this table is nested inside of another table, so it hides the containing td as well.

Comment: Then use Denys' suggestion; also: why wasn't that detail in the question? Could you [edit] to include it, as it's definitely relevant to the problem.

Comment: Ugh, no you are right it works. My eyes are playing tricks on me, thanks. And thanks for the truncated version!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to silently hide "Image not found" icon when src source image is not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found)

Comment: @Jenny I suggest you close this question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a short line like this: `$('img[src="null"]').parents('td:first').hide();`

If need to target all of the parent td ancestors  `$('img[src="null"]').parents('td').hide();`  remove pseudo :first selector,

Comment: `parents`, not `parent`. Fixed for you.

Comment: Hi niutech it's should be 'parent' in order to hide the right and immediate mother td, the 'parents' will hide every td elements that owns this img . If this whole table were inside a  'td',  will hide entire table, which is not intended in this question it seems. gonna change back parent.

Comment: In the code provided above `<img src="null">` is inside `<label>`, not `<td>` and `parent()` looks only one level up the DOM.

Comment: Hi niutech I checked to be u you are right,  anyway,  if 'parents' is used must use :first pseudo selector in order to hide only immediate td parent.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution using jQuery:

```
$('td:has(img[src="null"])').hide();
```

or slightly faster:

```
$('td').has('img[src="null"]').hide();
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit as to why the second version is supposed to be faster?

Comment: @garglblarg It uses the native `querySelectorAll` method to find `td`, as opposed to the custom `:has()` selector, which is not supported natively.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with this

```
<img onerror="this.parent.style.display='none'" src=".." />
```