# onerror javascript to alternate the other image and .....if other image not available want display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello  I can change my image to other image if it has no image.

```
<img src="test.png" onerror="if (this.src != 'pic_back.png') this.src = 'pic_back.png';" width="80" >
```

but I don't know  **how to hide the other image  if it has no other image too.** (if not have both main image and alternate image, then I want to use css display:none)

I know how to hide image but in this case, the onerror event has change to other image already, so I cannot use the onerror event again? so it's not duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to silently hide "Image not found" icon when src source image is not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found)

Comment: I know how to hide image   but in this case, the onerror event has change to other image already, so I cannot use the onerror event again? so it's not duplicate

Comment: Are you talking about the flashing missing image?