# html img hide broken icon, show alt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Do you know how to hide the classic “Image not found” or broken icon, but the alt still exist from a rendered HTML page when an image file is not found? 
Like this, 
`<img id="testImg" src="#" alt="No Image"/>` :
[image]

change to: No Image (show the alt only)

Any working method using JavaScript/jQuery/CSS?
Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to silently hide "Image not found" icon when src source image is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

1. Create a text node element based on the `alt` text
2. Insert the text node before the `img`
3. Remove the `img`, or hide it if you want

```js
function doSomething(elem){
  var alt = document.createTextNode( elem.getAttribute('alt') );
  
  elem.parentNode.insertBefore( alt, elem );
  
  elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
}
```

```html
<img src="actual_image_src"  alt="helloworld" onerror="doSomething(this)" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
     $(function(){
          $('img').error(function(){
            $(this).css('opacity' ,0);
            $(this).next('.alt').text($(this).attr("alt"));
          });
      })
```

```css
        .alt {
          opacity:0;
          float: left;
        }

        .alt:hover {
          opacity:1;
        }
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <img src="image_src"  alt="helloworld"  />
            <span class="alt"></span>
```

Comment: @FanLee, I have done it with `jQuery `, I hope it will help

Comment: @FanLee , you can see that answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006339/5940860
I think it's good idea as well to replace it with another background img

Answer (score -3):

You can fix this using the code below :

```
<img src="actual_image_src" onerror="this.src='on_error_image_src'"/>
```

Also you can use `display:none`  css , if u dont want to 
show anything at all.

```
<img src="actual_image_src" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```