# How to hide ugly picture which css if not available?

Tags: html, css

If the logo.png picture is not available, then it is hidden along with the logo from css.

```
<div class="logo">
<img  src="logo.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;style='display:none;'"/>
</div>
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/dzanis/t5Lg2ay0/

TODO
The question is solved by replacing the transparent image

```
<div class="logo">
<img  src="logo.png" onerror="this.src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzanis/dex1m47L/

Comment: so, what exactly is your question mate?

Comment: Sorry I did not put a question mark

Comment: your code is working, what you want to do ?

Comment: when src source image is not found. [Check the link below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found)

Comment: Thanks, works by replacing transparent gifs. http://jsfiddle.net/dzanis/95bLzae4/

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
<img src="http://aqualight.atspace.eu/logo.pngs" onerror='this.style.display = "none"' />
```

**Using CSS**

```js
function onImgError(ev) {
  ev.className = "error";
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
}

.error {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.twentyonepilots.com/sites/g/files/g2000004896/f/Sample%202_0.jpdg" onerror='onImgError(this)' />
```

Comment: he asked about error with css. This will only detect errors with src

Comment: This hides the entire block logo